# ThreeJS GLTFLoader material array

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to load a model using GLTFLoader and apply different color for each face of the object(cube) using material array. But it doesn't work.

```
            var materials = [ new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x552811,specular: 0x222222,shininess: 25}),
                              new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x552811,specular: 0x222222,shininess: 25})];

            loader = new GLTFLoader();
            loader.load( "./Model/cube.glb", function ( gltf ) {
                 var geometry = gltf.scene.children[ 2 ].geometry;
                 mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
                 scene.add( mesh );
            } );
```

If I change the material array to single material object it works, like

```
     mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials[0] );
```

I thought the problem is with giving array to mesh material, but if create the mesh manually and give the array as material, then it also works.

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,materials);
scene.add(mesh);
```

The problem is only when the mesh is loaded using `GLTFLoader` and and try to apply material array. Same is happening with OBJLoader also. What could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `BoxBufferGeometry`, the resulting geometry automatically has [groups](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups) data defined, which are a precondition for using multiple materials. I highly assume that the geometry resulting from loading `cube.glb` does not have any groups and thus applying multiple materials is not possible.

`three.js R108`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, right now I am using blender to create the object and export to glb format, can you please give some hint how I can solve it.

Comment: It should work if you already assign in Blender to each side of the cube a different material.

Comment: You are right when I debug the code I have seen that for loaded object the group  array is empty. I will check in blender side as per your suggestion. On more doubt is it possible to make the group from threejs side based in each face. What I have to implement  is apply different texture on each face of loaded object.